# How to configure dynamic allocation for PySpark in Jupyter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I was using Zeppelin for pyspark scripting. Now i want to start scripting in Jupyter. I am not able to configure the following dynamic allocations.

```
livy.spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
livy.spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors 6
livy.spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
```

How can i do that?

I have already configured the below items just by changing the config Json file.

```
livy.spark.executor.cores 4
livy.spark.executor.memory 4g
```